# How to detect Vetcor3 points or RegionTypes for eyes in ARCore

Tags: android, arcore, android-augmented-reality

ARCore defines only three regions that can be used to get poses. They are

- AugmentedFace.RegionType.FOREHEAD_LEFT
- AugmentedFace.RegionType.FOREHEAD_RIGHT
- AugmentedFace.RegionType.NOSE_TIP

But how to get other regions like eyes, center of fore head, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question was asked in Github. That will solve the above issue. Refer the following [link](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/563)